# Generated Routes with bloc Flutter

Tags: flutter, bloc, flutter-navigation, flutter-routes

I'm developing a simple Flutter application with `generatedRoutes` and `bloc` state management library/pattern. I've one simple `cubit` which generates a random number and a single `Home Screen` with a button to generate new random number. **On running the app, a white screen is keep displaying and in debugging console, I'm getting `isolate` related error  and notification continuously shows that Xcode build is running as shown below:-**
[image: debug Consol]

Here is my code:

**NavigationCubit and NavigationState**

```
class NavigationState {
  final int number;
  NavigationState(this.number);
}

class NavigationCubit extends Cubit<NavigationState> {
  NavigationCubit():super(NavigationState(0));

  void onStateChange() {

    var r = Random();
    emit(NavigationState(r.nextInt(1000)));
  }      
}
```

**AppRouter Class**

```
class AppRouter {

  Route generateRoutes(RouteSettings settings) {
    switch(settings.name) {
      case '/':
        return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) =>
        BlocProvider<NavigationCubit>( create: (context) => NavigationCubit(),
          child: const HomeScreen(),
        ));
      default:return MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => const ErrorScreen());
    
    }
  }
}
```

**HomeScreen and ErrorScreen**

```
class HomeScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const HomeScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: const Text("Welcome to page routes"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: [
            BlocBuilder<NavigationCubit, NavigationState>(
              builder: (context, state) => Text(state.number.toString()),),
              ElevatedButton(onPressed: () {
                context.read<NavigationCubit>().onStateChange();
              }, child: const Text("Generate"))

          ],
        )),
    );
  }
}

class ErrorScreen extends StatelessWidget {
  const ErrorScreen({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body:  Center(child: Text("Error in routing")),
    );
  }
}
```

**Main file (main.dart)**

```
void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  MyApp({super.key});

  final router = AppRouter();

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Generated Routes Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),

      onGenerateRoute: router.generateRoutes,
      initialRoute: '/',
    );
  }
}
```

**Flutter_bloc dependency version: `flutter_bloc: ^8.1.2`**

I've tried multiple solutions, one provided by [This](https://codersmagazine.medium.com/using-generated-route-production-grade-flutter-app-wechat-clone-7b67ffbbe37a) where all the `cubits/blocs` are disposed manually, but no luck.

How to solve this problem, what's wrong with my approach.

Answer (score 0):

that error is get because your app is not run from main.dart file you can fixed that error by add launch.json file in vscode to folder .vscode in your project file contain

```
{
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Flutter",
        "type": "dart",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "lib/main.dart"
    }
  ]
}
```